# Build in wine with my program

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, wine

I have developed an application designed for commercial use. Application is based on Qt. But I have to use Themida, the anti-cracking software. So I need to compile this software for Linux/MacOS as well, but there is not any obfuscation software like themida. I have an idea.. Is it possible to embed wine to application? As google picasa for example... If yes then how to do that? Are there any examples...

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to embed wine to application?

You can't "embed" it, because it is a huge collection of dlls. Another problem is that wine is LGPL, so "embedding it" (static link with LGPL) is "no go" for proprietary/closed-source app.

I think you should be able to link with it dynamically.
2 years ago it was possible to make application link with [winelib](http://www.winehq.org/site/winelib) and get access to wine facilities this way. Haven't tried that myself.

It will be probably easier to simply compile application for windows, and then ensure it works under wine - less hassle. However, if I were you, I'd attempt to find different protection scheme - any scheme that doesn't rely on windows-specific technology. Relying on wine to make your app work isn't a very good idea (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

You do not "embed" Wine. Wine is a set of libraries installed on linux that act as a middle-tier between a windows program and the linux system.

Simply compile your app on Windows, preferably wrap it into an installer with all your dependent .dll's like "themida" and possibly the Qt .dll's.

Then install wine on your linux system, try to install your app and cross fingers ;)